# UIDatePicker september 1978 bug in ios 4.x

Tags: ios4, uidatepicker

Using a date picker in my app it is impossible to select a date in **September 1978** other than September 1st.
If you have i.e 8 September 1979 and you change just the year to 1978 the day jumps automatically to 1 and it is impossible to change to any other day (they are all greyed out ).

From other forums other persons report this bug also in the built-in contacts app in the birthday field.

My application is built with XCode 3.2.5 + ios 4.2
The problem seems present only on devices with ios 4.x: I have tried with an iPod with ios 3.1.3 and the same app is working fine.

I have tried compiling and running with XCode 3.2.6 + ios 4.3 but the problem persists.
The iPhone simulator (with ios 4.3) gives the same problem when adding a birthday in the contacts application.

Someone knows about a workaround for this UIDatePicker issue?
Unfortunately on developer-Apple site I cannot find an exhaustive list of fixed bugs / known issues...

Friendshiplanet

Comment: I just went to http://www.epochconverter.com/#tools and punched in Sept 1 1978 0:0:0 and it gave me 273456000.  That doesn't look like it's problematic, so the timestamp hunch is a dead-end.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this was a problem related to the TimeZone. So in Italy time zone the bug appears on septemner 1978, in other timezones the bug may appear in other months. This explain why Apple support and other did not find a way to reproduce it.
Luckily in iOS 6.0 this problem disappeared!

So the best workaround now is to compile the code against iOS 6.0 (or above) libraries.